Getting "Abnormal build process termination: " while building the application in intellij
Abnormal build process termination: 
nice -n 10 /Users/yashwandhare/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-22.0.2/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Djna.boot.library.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jna/aarch64" -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.noclasspath=true --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED -Dexternal.project.config=/Users/yashwandhare/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.3/projects/niffler.36f9b025/external_build_system -Dcompile.parallel=true -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Didea.IntToIntBtree.page.size=32768 -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-532604766655091619 -Djps.use.dependency.graph=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=IN -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2024.3 "-Didea.home.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents" "-Didea.config.path=/Users/yashwandhare/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.3" "-Didea.plugins.path=/Users/yashwandhare/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.3/plugins" -Djps.log.dir=/Users/yashwandhare/Library/Logs/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.3/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=21.0.5 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/yashwandhare/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.3/compile-server/niffler_99297dbb/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder.fs.case.sensitive=false -Dcompilation.charts=false -Djps.kotlin.home=/Users/yashwandhare/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.3/kotlin-dist-for-ide/1.6.21 -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=/var/folders/zq/jpv9zlnx77j6qvbkcn5qvj7w0000gp/T/kotlin-idea-10739428649398147487-is-running -Dide.propagate.context=false -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/util-8.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/util_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/platform-loader.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/annotations.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/trove.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jetbrains.kotlinx.metadata.jvm.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/netty-codec-protobuf.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/protobuf.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jps-model.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/forms_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/lib-client.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Users/yashwandhare/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-jps-plugin/1.6.21/kotlin-jps-plugin-1.6.21.jar:/Users/yashwandhare/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-daemon-client/1.6.21/kotlin-daemon-client-1.6.21.jar:/Users/yashwandhare/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm/1.5.0/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.jar:/Users/yashwandhare/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-build-common/1.6.21/kotlin-build-common-1.6.21.jar:/Users/yashwandhare/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.6.21/kotlin-reflect-1.6.21.jar:/Users/yashwandhare/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.21/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.21.jar:/Users/yashwandhare/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.6.21/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.21.jar:/Users/yashwandhare/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.jar:/Users/yashwandhare/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-util-io/1.6.21/kotlin-util-io-1.6.21.jar:/Users/yashwandhare/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-util-klib/1.6.21/kotlin-util-klib-1.6.21.jar:/Users/yashwandhare/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-util-klib-metadata/1.6.21/kotlin-util-klib-metadata-1.6.21.jar:/Users/yashwandhare/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-native-utils/1.6.21/kotlin-native-utils-1.6.21.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/util-8.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps/java-compiler-charts-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/platform-langInjection/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 56648 2a1d78c1-d8a1-439d-a787-6fedde34a9c5 /Users/yashwandhare/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.3/compile-server
Be careful, logger will be shut down earlier than application: Unable to make field private static java.util.IdentityHashMap java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.hooks accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6d03e736
Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:56648; reason: Bad file descriptor: /127.0.0.1:56648
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Bad file descriptor: /127.0.0.1:56648
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Bad file descriptor
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:1060)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:384)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.handle(AbstractNioChannel.java:432)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioIoHandler$DefaultNioRegistration.handle(NioIoHandler.java:386)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioIoHandler.processSelectedKey(NioIoHandler.java:585)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioIoHandler.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioIoHandler.java:530)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioIoHandler.processSelectedKeys(NioIoHandler.java:503)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioIoHandler.run(NioIoHandler.java:478)
    at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadIoEventLoop.runIo(SingleThreadIoEventLoop.java:184)
    at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadIoEventLoop.run(SingleThreadIoEventLoop.java:156)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1123)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Exiting.



I was trying to build the kotlin application, but in turn got this error while building, the error is now happening for all the applications I'm trying to run on intellij

Do you have other applications that might block access to the JPS process at 127.0.0.1:56648 ? If possible can you telnet to check if the port is really accessible?

I have tried doing lsof, only application running on this port is idea.
